# Could I save pictures from different picture boxes as individual ones, with Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2012

If I were to load an image into VS and split it into two pieces, one in each of the two given pictureboxes, could I somehow save each split piece of the picture as an individual image? If so, how?

Comment: "If I were to load an image into VS and split it into two pieces"

How would you do that?

Comment: With some code this http://pastebin.com/8RZwZt7Y.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you don't load it into VS, but into your programm and split it there the rest is simple. A picturebox can save its image like this:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"c:\temp\somename.jpg");
```

Comment: I thank you. That works. Do you know of how I could possibly combine the pictures back together after I save them as individual images?

Comment: You mean in code? Well you should study the code that splits them. The start is to have a bitmap of the right size, then copy the portions to the right positions. A bit bit ichty but not terribly hard. You sure it makes sense?  ;-)

Comment: Yes, what you have said makes sense.

Comment: Um, are your problems resolvd? If not, which are still open?